# How to zip two columns together in a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

For example columns are setup as:

```
A | B
-----
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
4 | d
5 | e
```

I want to be able to make column C be like this:

```
 C
---
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 a
 b
 c
 d
 e
```

via formula. The two columns will actually be in different sheets and both will be updated over time. I don’t really care about order but I am not sure how to get this to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `VMERGE` script from the script gallary:

[image]

The script you just installed, makes it possible to combine multiple ranges into one: 
`=VMERGE(range1,range2, ect)`

See example file I've prepared for you to play with: [VMERGE and Ranges](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdE02VVhhVXpMcDhiNWlLMG9LRkxtQUE&usp=sharing)