# How Do I Combine Columns In Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I need to combine multiple columns into a single column, so:

```
one     four    seven
two     five    eight
three   six     nine
```

Becomes:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
```

Comment: That's not possible with plain old formula's. Have a look at this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/39292/29140

Comment: Related: [How to zip two columns together in a Google Spreadsheet](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44915/how-to-zip-two-columns-together-in-a-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Unfortunately that merges sheets, not columns.

Comment: It works for column ranges as well.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra since the answer to this and the other thread I cited above are the same should they be considered duplicates? (Great script find BTW)

Comment: @batpigandme Please flag the other question as a duplicate, as this one is most likely to get marked...

Comment: **Update**: [See this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79577), the accepted one is for the old version of Sheets.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following formula can be used to merge one column after another:

```
={A1:A5; M1:M5}
```

Comment: This is not good if you have a lot of blank cells.

Comment: I needed to solve the blank cells issue and got this to work:
`=Filter(({C2:C;E2:E;G2:G;I2:I}),({C2:C;E2:E;G2:G;I2:I})<>"")`

Answer (score 9):

If the columns are A, E, G (for example), then the following command combines them:

```
={filter(A:A, len(A:A)); filter(E:E, len(E:E)); filter(G:G, len(G:G))}
```

Here, I first filter the columns by `len()` to remove blank cells. Then I combine the columns together.

An example combining columns in different sheets:

```
={filter(sheetone!A:A, len(sheetone!A:A)); filter(sheettwo!A:A, len(sheettwo!A:A))}
```

Adapted from [my answer from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442099/stacking-multiple-columns-on-to-one/31031241#31031241).

Comment: e.g. merge(and sort|uniq) 3 columns excluding first header row ```=UNIQUE(SORT({filter(B2:B, len(B2:B)); filter(C2:C, len(C2:C)); filter(D2:D, len(D2:D))}))```

Comment: and e.g. re-combine columns showing side-by-side comparison if original columns(B,C,D) contain item in the merged column ```=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($F2,B$2:B,0)),"",$F2)```

Answer (score 0):

In the new Google Spreadsheets, the script gallery has been replaced with the add-on store.

You can try this function to combine two columns

```
=unique(transpose(split(join(";",A:A)&join(";",B:B),";")))
```

Answer (score -1):

Install the `VMERGE` script from the script gallery:

[image: screen shot]

The script you just installed, makes it possible to combine multiple ranges into one: 
`=VMERGE(range1,range2, ect)`

See example file I've prepared for you to play with: [VMERGE and Ranges](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdE02VVhhVXpMcDhiNWlLMG9LRkxtQUE&usp=sharing)

Comment: Beautiful. Much obliged.

Comment: At this time the Script Gallery is available only for old spreadsheets that had not being migrated yet.

Comment: Yeah; no more VMERGE still.